# Usage of the ternary operator without a false case

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Why is the content of `DoSomeThing()` not translatable to the ternary expression used in `DoAnotherThing()`?

```
public void DoSomeThing()
{
    if (someBool)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("someBool is true");
    }
    else // Redundant, left for clarity 
    {
        return ; 
    }
}

public void DoAnotherThing()
{
    someBool ? Debug.WriteLine("someBool is true") : return;
}
```

Sure I could use the `if` statement on a single line like this...

```
public void DoAnotherThing()
{
    if (someBool) Debug.WriteLine("someBool is true");
}
```

But still curious. Is there a way to leave the `false` case away?

This won't work: `someBool ? Debug.WriteLine("someBool is true");` nor will something like this `someBool ? Debug.WriteLine("someBool is true") : return;`

Comment: not sure why this would be added, you're basically asking for just an alternate syntax to the if-statement? it would do exactly the same thing in every way - the if statement is already plenty short

Comment: [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) output is void.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a **TERN**ary operator would it

Comment: A ternary is not an alternative to `if`..`else`; it is an expression that must evaluate to a specific type.

Comment: I think it would make the code less verbose. A ternary expression is also doing the same thing as an if-else-statement, but we are glad to have it. As it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @Matze No, a ternary is not doing the same thing as an if/else.  The former is an expression and evaluates to a value.  The latter is a statement and doesn't evaluate to a value.

Comment: As for the duplicate, I feel the second answer where it's stated *"It's not meant to optionally take some action... it's meant to evaluate one expression or another, and that be the result of the expression.

If you only want to perform an action when some condition is met, use an if statement - that's precisely what it's there for."* is the right interpretation and foots well with what @Amy stated.

Comment: [Specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) says that _The type of `consequent` and `alternative` must be the same, or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other_ `WriteLine` returns `void`, `return` is just return, it's no a type

Comment: Okay thank you guys. I think I got it. One is an expression and the other is a statement. But still I don't understand why I can't reach the same behaviour, e.g. using the discard operator. Maybe I am just confused... I could use something like this `_ = someBool ? true : false`, which of course doesn't make sense. But still the both cases get evaluated.

Comment: @Matze Because the ternary expression in the form of `condition ? A : B`, A and B must both evaluate to the same type.  If they don't, the entire expression is invalid.  The discard variable doesn't have a type, so it can't be used as A or B.  The entire expression *must* evaluate to a value.